# HTTP PUT HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, spring, httpurlconnection, http-put

I'm trying to update a register on a table by sending a PUT request.

1) Headers

- Accept application/json
- Content-Type application/json

2) Body (example):

```
{
    "sys_id": "05c9f2de0f5a8b00bad5e0ba42050eee",
    "u_number": "PASS0001028",
    "u_caller.u_id_peoplesoft": "",
    "sys_created_on": "2017-11-10 11:53:04",
    "u_daily_amount": "1",
    "u_state": "20",
    "u_calendar_day.u_id": "",
    "u_operator.u_id": ""
}
```

3) Basic Authorization

I've been trying this code so far:

```
public static void atualizaServiceNow(ValeTransporte valeTransporte) throws URISyntaxException {

        try {

            System.out.println("urlBase: " + urlBase);
            URL url = new URL(urlBase);

            String plainCreds = Constant.SERVICENOW_USER + ":" + Constant.SERVICENOW_PW;
            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsVT = gson.toJson(valeTransporte);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(jsVT));
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("Ok!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I'm getting error on this line "OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();" it jumps to the catch printing "Connection reset by peer: socket write error".

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:886)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:857)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:727)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1216)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1128)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.luizalabs.util.ServiceNowUtil.atualizaServiceNow(ServiceNowUtil.java:57)
at com.luizalabs.resource.ValeTransporteResource.inclusaoVT(ValeTransporteResource.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What could be  happening?

Thanks

Comment: since you didn't give a stack trace it's just an assumption: in case of any http exceptions connection doesn't provide a data through _getOutputStream()_ getter. In this case you have to use _getErrorStream()_

Comment: stack trace added

Comment: RST to CCS _may_ mean server wanted you to send client authentication aka client certificate and you didn't. Best if you can check server log(s) to see what it thinks the problem is. Else try to get a wire trace with Wireshark tcpdump or similar to see exactly what is happening in what order (and share somewhere accessible like pastebin); or if you have another client that works, compare to (exactly) what that does.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't know exactly how to do it. Could you share a way and an expected output?

Comment: What or which 'it' are you doing? _I_ would look at the server log(s) but how to do that depends on the server, which you didn't identify or describe. What you find will depend on the server and the problem, which could be several different things.